# Quill editor contents is cleared when I select another textbox in form

Tags: blazor, quill, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server app that uses the Quill editor. If I was to add some content in the Quill editor, then go to enter text in another textbox on the same form, then click to enter text in another textbox, the contents of the Quill editor is lost.

Chrome Console shows the following erros when I go from one textbox to another -

> WASM: Unhandled exception rendering component: blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: item is null blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: selectItem@https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js:9693:7 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: IconPicker@https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js:9684:11 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: buildPickers/this.pickers<@https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js:6739:18 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: buildPickers@https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js:6734:30 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: extendToolbar@https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js:9851:12 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: addModule@https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js:6703:14 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: init/<@https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js:6049:17 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: init@https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js:6047:41 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: Quill@https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js:1113:16 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: createQuill@https://localhost:44323/BlazorQuill.js:17:13 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: beginInvokeJSFromDotNet/r<@https://localhost:44323/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:9610 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: beginInvokeJSFromDotNet@https://localhost:44323/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:9579 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: _mono_wasm_invoke_js_marshalled@https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.js:1:178941 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[132]:0x0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[6361]:0x11d724 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[1463]:0x3f118 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[616]:0x1373b blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[616]:0x1eb39 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[616]:0x1eb17 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[616]:0x1eb39 3 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[616]:0x1eb17 10 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[616]:0x1eb39 2 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[616]:0x1eb17 6 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[5230]:0xf3546 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[3309]:0xa1906 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[1352]:0x39ba7 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[449]:0xd78f blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[1761]:0x4f8aa blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: @https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.wasm:wasm-function[3549]:0xac258 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method@https://localhost:44323/_framework/wasm/mono.js:1:202599 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: callMethod@https://localhost:44323/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:39515 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: endInvokeJSFromDotNet@https://localhost:44323/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:37995 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: beginInvokeJSFromDotNet/<@https://localhost:44323/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:9663 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM: blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x2b88ab8 + 0x0004a> in <c50882760828481c927e00b7db67d1a5>:0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM:   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () <0x2b88a08 + 0x00006> in :0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM:   at HOG.BlazorClient.Pages.admin.Blog.AddEditItem.OnAfterRenderAsync (System.Boolean firstRender) <0x2b68a78 + 0x002f6> in :0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618
>   WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x2104898 + 0x000be> in <44d78cab266c4647aa96aadd4455da2c>:0 blazor.webassembly.js:1:35618

Here is my form -

```
<EditForm Model="@PostObject">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@PostObject.Title" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => PostObject.Title)" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Preview Text</label>
                    <InputTextArea class="form-control" @bind-Value="@PostObject.PreviewText" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => PostObject.PreviewText)" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <div id="toolbar">
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <select class="ql-font">
                                <option selected=""></option>
                                <option value="serif"></option>
                                <option value="monospace"></option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="ql-size">
                                <option value="small"></option>
                                <option selected=""></option>
                                <option value="large"></option>
                                <option value="huge"></option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                            <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                            <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                            <button class="ql-strike"></button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <select class="ql-color"></select>
                            <select class="ql-background"></select>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
                            <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
                            <button class="ql-indent" value="-1"></button>
                            <button class="ql-indent" value="+1"></button>
                            <select class="ql-align">
                                <option selected=""></option>
                                <option value="center"></option>
                                <option value="right"></option>
                                <option value="justify"></option>
                            </select>
                            <button class="ql-image"></button>
                            <button class="ql-video"></button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-link"></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div @ref="@divEditorElement" />

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Tags</label>
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@PostObject.Tags" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => PostObject.Tags)" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>META Tags</label>
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@PostObject.MetaTags" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => PostObject.MetaTags)" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>META Description</label>
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@PostObject.MetaDesc" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => PostObject.MetaDesc)" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => HandleValidSubmit())">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </EditForm>
```

Comment: This should give you what you need: https://github.com/Blazored/TextEditor

Comment: Also see this to see how I was able to make Quill work with Blazor: http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4365/Creating-Reusable-Custom-Blazor-Controls.aspx